# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - March 28, 2019

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (EST):** March 28, 2019, 6:30 p.m.

**Date/Time (UTC):** March 28, 2019, 23:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/258465319/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on March 28th, at 6:30 p.m., at [Roam in Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us)!

Parking will be complimentary. We will be providing prepaid validations to all our guests. Dinner and drinks will be served.

We are looking forward to a great meeting!

### Agenda

- 6:30 - 7:00: Food, drinks, and social time
- 7:00 - 7:35: [George Chang](https://twitter.com/sitecoregeorge) ([Perficient Digital](https://www.perficientdigital.com/)) - Sitecore Host: Why It Should Matter to You
- 7:35 - 8:10: [Jason Wilkerson](https://twitter.com/longhorntaco) ([Wilkerson Consulting](https://citizensitecore.com/)) - Sitecore Cortex: From Introduction to Extension
- 8:10 - 8:45: [Jill Grozalsky](https://twitter.com/Jgrozalsky) ([Brainjocks](https://brainjocks.com/)) - The Lifecycle of Goals and Personalization in Projects
- 8:45: Closing comments, end of event

### Presentations

#### Sitecore Host: Why It Should Matter to You

**Speaker**: [George Chang](https://twitter.com/sitecoregeorge) - [Perficient Digital](https://www.perficientdigital.com/)

Sitecore Host brings a new paradigm to the Sitecore ecosystem by moving the platform towards a microservice-style architecture on ASP.NET Core. What does this mean to you as a developer or a DevOps engineer or a CTO? In this session, we will talk about how this changes the Sitecore landscape, what benefits Sitecore Host and a microservices architecture can bring to the platform, and a demo of a Sitecore Host plugin using a message broker to accommodate for scalable Sitecore Host applications.

Join us in diving into what Sitecore Host can bring to real world scenarios and the possibilities of a microservices-style Sitecore for the future.

#### Sitecore Cortex: From Introduction to Extension

**Speaker**: [Jason Wilkerson](https://twitter.com/longhorntaco) - [Wilkerson Consulting](https://citizensitecore.com/)

Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence are the hottest buzz words these days and Marketers are eagerly searching for ways to incorporate this new landscape of technology into the journey of their customers. Cortex may be the answer to that search! In this session, we'll look at a fictional retail hair salon, Habitat Hair, and demonstrate how, through analyzing all of the xDB data we have on a customer as well as their purchase history, we can leverage Cortex to recommend products to individual customers, segment users based on visit frequency to optimize daily appointment scheduling, etc... We'll also show code examples of how Data Scientists could create task chains of distributed tasks to accomplish these goals.

#### The Lifecycle of Goals and Personalization in Projects

**Speaker**: [Jill Grozalsky](https://twitter.com/Jgrozalsky) - [Brainjocks](https://brainjocks.com/)

- Translating business goals/objectives to digital goals that are measurable and provide insight into the performance of an experience
- User audience information to define segments
- Identifying areas of personalization in the design phase
- Documenting goal/personalization requirements
- QA'ing goals and personalization prior to launch